# AWS API request rate limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, limit, amazon-dynamodb, rate

*Update*: Keep-alive wasn't set on the AWS client. My fix was

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.httpOptions.agent = new https.Agent({
  keepAlive: true
});
```

I finally managed to debug it by using the Node `--prof` flag. Then using the [node-tick-processor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-tick-processor) to analyze the output (it's a packaged version of a tool distributed in the Node/V8 source code). Most of the processing time was spent in SSL processing and that's when I thought to check whether or not is used keep-alive.

---

TL;DR Getting throttled by AWS when the number of requests is less than the configured DynamoDB throughput. Is there a request rate limit for all APIs?

---

I'm having a hard time finding documentation about the rate limiting of AWS APIs.

An application that I'm testing now is making about 80 requests per second to DynamoDB. This is a mix of PUTs and GETs. My DynamoDB table is configured with a throughput of: 250 reads / 250 writes. In the table CloudWatch metrics, the reads peak at 24 and the writes at 59 during the test period.

This is a sample of my response times. First, subsecond response times.

```
2015-10-07T15:28:55.422Z 200 in 20 milliseconds in request to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2015-10-07T15:28:55.423Z 200 in 22 milliseconds in request to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

A lot longer, but fine...

```
2015-10-07T15:29:33.907Z 200 in 244 milliseconds in request to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2015-10-07T15:29:33.910Z 200 in 186 milliseconds in request to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

The requests are piling up...

```
2015-10-07T15:32:41.103Z 200 in 1349 milliseconds in request to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2015-10-07T15:32:41.104Z 200 in 1181 milliseconds in request to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

...no...

```
2015-10-07T15:41:09.425Z 200 in 6596 milliseconds in request to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2015-10-07T15:41:09.428Z 200 in 5902 milliseconds in request to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I went and got some tea...

```
2015-10-07T15:44:26.463Z 200 in 13900 milliseconds in request to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2015-10-07T15:44:26.464Z 200 in 12912 milliseconds in request to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Anyway, I stopped the test, but this is a Node.js application so a bunch of sockets were left open waiting for my requests to AWS to complete. I got response times > 60 seconds.

My DynamoDB throughput wasn't used much, so I assume that the limit is in API requests but I can't find any information on it. What's interesting is that the `200` part of the log entries is the response code from AWS which I got by [hacking a bit of the SDK](https://github.com/mqsoh/aws-sdk-js/commit/9887e69a213ded4dd50c6e3bd62c76b7d84d90df). I think AWS is supposed to return 429s -- all their SDKs implement exponential backoff.

Anyway -- I assumed that I could make as many requests to DynamoDB as configured throughput. Is that right? ...or what?

Comment: Hmm, that seems long even if the client is auto-retrying on rate limiting. It might be within the default tolerance if the errors are retryable, I'm not sure what the defaults are. If you want to inspect the retries you could add a `AWS.events.on('retry', function(response) {inspect response}`. You could also try lowering the max retries by a lot to see errors bubble up faster - `new AWS.DynamoDB({maxRetries: 1})` to get some more information.

Comment: Also, do you see any `ThrottledRequests`, `ReadThrottleEvents`, `UserError`, or `WriteThrottleEvents` on the metric graphs for the table [(DynamoDB metrics)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/MonitoringDynamoDB.html)?

Comment: No `retry` events are executed. I also added in a `complete` listener and checked `response.retryCount` -- all 0. `maxRetries` didn't cause any changes in behavior either, of course.

No ThrottledRequests (but I don't see the Read/Write version of this metric anywhere). There are UserErrors, but I don't think there are enough to account for the problem -- peaks at 100 per minute.

(I'll investigate UserErrors tomorrow. It's very confusing to me since I have error handling in all my API callbacks and nothing is printed to the logs. Also, these are supposedly 400-grade responses that I never see

Comment: Yes, you can make as many requests as your provisioned throughput allows, though some requests may consume more than one unit... but what you are seeing does not look like throttling from AWS and you can almost certainly dismiss any thought of some "overall" API limit with traffic volumes this small. It looks more like you have issues in your application, some kind of unexpected blocking or resource exhaustion locally.

Comment: I see. Thank you, @Michael-sqlbot.

Comment: A packet trace with a tool like Wireshark's `tshark` may tell you something if you observe the timing of events in the sloooow responses.  I would expect to see connect open or request send happening later than you expect, or response body arriving earlier than you expect, based on what the app appears to be doing.

Comment: Do you have any Global Secondary Indexes on your table?  It is possible for GSIs to prevent you from getting the full throughput allocated, but it sounds like there may be other issues.